# ImportError No module named BeautifulSoup - path error

Tags: python, macos, path, beautifulsoup, lxml

I've downloaded beautiful soup to use in python and all was fine but it shows this error:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
ImportError: No module named BeautifulSoup
```

after a good google and search on here I tried

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

but get essentially the same error.

```
ImportError: No module named bs4
```

The code I am trying to execute is below.

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import re

doc = ['&lt;html>&lt;head>&lt;title>Page title&lt;/title>&lt;/head>',
       '&lt;body><p id="firstpara" align="center">This is paragraph <b>one</b>.',
       '<p id="secondpara" align="blah">This is paragraph <b>two</b>.',
       '&lt;/html>']
soup = BeautifulSoup(''.join(doc))

print soup.prettify()
```

I've installed beautifulsoup4 and I'm using mac OS X if that counts for anything

EDIT as a few comments said, I had a spelling error however after correcting this the same error is still being thrown up despite having the correct spelling.

EDIT I've tried to use lxml as an alternative and it gives me the same error just with lxml, I had the same problem with requests too so I'm assuming its a problem with an incorrect path rather than the import itself hence the slight title change

EDIT as requested output of which -a python:

```
/usr/local/bin/python
/usr/bin/python
```

Comment: You've got a couple of different spellings on BeautifulSoup in your question - this could be a simple typo in your code? The error message will show exactly the spelling it is trying to import.

Comment: check the spelling `from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup`

Comment: @srowland just went through to make sure everything was spelt correctly, had a few mistakes - definitely been staring at this for too long! however still throwing the same error up

Comment: Ah OK, this is the error you would expect if BeautifulSoup wasn't installed - how did you install it?

Comment: @srowland I installed it using pip, if I attempt to install again it says it's already been installed.

Comment: Ok, that sounds perfect, do you run Python from the command line (or the same place you run pip from)?

Comment: @srowland no, I'm using it on netbeans

Comment: I'm not familiar with netbeans, but it sounds like it might be using it's own version of Python, which might not have BeautifulSoup installed?

Comment: @srowland I'll have a look into that, thanks!

Comment: @rosie_hyde, netbeans does not have it's own version of python, the problem is you have multiple versions of python and you are using an interpreter that the packages was not installed for. Add the output of  `which -a python` to your question

Comment: @PadraicCunningham added!

Comment: Ok,  you have a mismatch between what pip is pointing to and the interpreter you are using in netbeans.  You need to change the  interpreter in netbeans settings.

Comment: @rosie_hyde, follow the instructions here http://wiki.netbeans.org/NetBeansPythonTutorial#Setting_Your_Platform_Runtime all you need to do is specify the correct interpreter for your project

Answer (score 2):

> `from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup`

This is how you import the `BeautifulSoup` in beautifulsoup version 3.

And, since you have installed the [`beautifulsoup4` package](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/), you need to change your import to:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

And, you need to make sure you have `beautifulsoup4` installed in the same exact Python environment you are using to execute the script.

Comment: As stated in my question, I have tried this and no luck - even with the correct spelling

Comment: Please could you give more information on how to check if beautifulsoup4 is installed in the same Python environment as netbeans?